# Filter "value in list" with SQLObject ORM

Tags: python, orm, sqlobject

I wanted to use SQLObject to allow my co-workers to get some data from my MySQL database. Now I need to use filter "value in list" but I don't know how can I do that.

I choosed SQLObject because it looks simpler than for example Django ORM, but is there option to use filter "value in list"? In Django it is simply Class.objects.filter(value__in=list). I did not find an equivalent in the documentation of SQLObject but it is hard to believe that there is no such feature.

My list is not a range of values so

```py
AND(Class.q.value>list[0], Class.q.value<list[-1])
```

...does not solve my problem. I need something that works like this code in Django:

```py
Class.objects.filter(id__in=[1,13,100,17])
```

How can I do this using SQLObject? Can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlobject.sqlbuilder import IN
```

and use in your query:

```
IN(Class.q.value, list)
```

See [the docs](http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html#nested-sql-statements-subqueries) and [tests](http://sqlobject.org/_modules/sqlobject/tests/test_subqueries.html).

Comment: Thank you! You are saving my life :)